# How to pick all the rows after nth of a value until you come across another value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The best way to explain my situation is with an example.

[image]

In this example I want to pick all the rows after the third timestamp until I reach the flag. Once the flag is reached the counter is reset. Now again I want to keep traversing and pick the rows after 6th timestamp then the rows after 9th timestamp and so on.

Comment: Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking. You need to be asking an explicit question.

Comment: used an image instead

Comment: Please click on the example for an image

Comment: Please let me know if the example or the explanation is too difficult to understand

Comment: what have **you actually tried to achieve your results?** If you post your attempts, we can help you more easily.

Comment: Are they all the same?

Comment: The timestamps and flags are same. The item rows differ. Thanks.

Comment: I added a column to the left of col A and just above the first timestamp in that column I put the value as 1 in the cell. In the same new column one row down i.e. at the same row as timestamp I added this formula in the new column=IF(B4="timestamp",MOD((A3+1),3),A3). A3 here is the value 1 I populated earlier. I dragged this formula down to the very end. Later I would add a filter on this new row for 0's and those are the cells I need. Just wondering is there a way to do this better or automate it. Thanks.

Comment: When you say pick do you mean count?

Comment: No, when I say pick I mean select those rows.